# showing google calendar events in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use gem "gcal4ruby", "0.5.4" to fetch calender details from google calender and then show those information in rails view page. I am following  (http://blog.pebbleit.com/post/540819239/fetching-and-caching-google-calendar-data-in-rails) George Ornbo post.

```
class CalendarController < ApplicationController
service = GCal4Ruby::Service.new

service.authenticate("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
cal = GCal4Ruby::Calendar.find(
    service, 
    'YOUR_CALENDAR',
    {:scope => :first}
)
events = GCal4Ruby::Event.find(
    cal, 
    "", 
    {
     :range => {:start => Time.parse("08/04/2000"), 
     :end => Time.parse("09/04/2010")}
    }
)
end
```

I replaced username,password,service,start time and end time. When execute this I am getting following error

```
undefined method `calendars' for []:Array
app/controllers/calendar_controller.rb:12:in `event_display'
```

Anyone can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted worked in earlier versions (0.3.x) of GCal4Ruby, if I'm not mistaken. You probably have a more recent version of the gem and you're getting that error. Some things have changed in the gem... I'll try to go through a few (hopefully that will fix your errors).

First, GCal4Ruby now uses the gdata gem in the background, so the query calls have changed a bit. This affects the code above.

Second, as a result, `Calendar.find` doesn't use `:scope` anymore, so your find method is returning an array of calendars (instead of one Calendar object). The method definition is…

```
def self.find(service, query, args = {})
  …
end
```

… where `query` can either be a hash with an `:id => <id>` (which returns a Calendar object) or a string - with your calendar name, which is the option you're using. This will return an Array, so to get the first result, instead of `{:scope => :first}` you can now just get the .first element of the array. Your code would now be:

```
cal = GCal4Ruby::Calendar.find(service, 'YOUR_CALENDAR',{}).first
```

Also, fetching the events is broken there. There are a couple of ways of getting calendar events. One would be calling `cal.events` after getting your calendar, but that would fetch all the events. If you want to filter by a date range, or max-results, you need to query the Event class and pass the calendar ID as an arg. Event.find has exactly the same definition as Calendar.find, and works in almost exactly the same way (searches by id, or by query parameters). You can read the [source code for event.rb](http://gcal4ruby.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/lib/gcal4ruby/event.rb) and see how it works, it's also well documented.

Once you have your cal object from above, you can get it's events like:

```
events = GCal4Ruby::Event.find(service, "", {
    :calendar => cal.id, 'start-min' => Time.parse("08/04/2000").utc.xmlschema,
    'start-max' => Time.parse("06/01/2010").utc.xmlschema
})
```

Notice that both 'start-min' and 'start-max' are not symbols but strings, and that the dates are passed as xmlschema. From the event.rb comments:

> *args*:: a hash containing optional additional query paramters to use.  Limit a search to a single calendar by passing the calendar id as `{:calendar => calendar.id}`.  See [here](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#RetrievingEvents) and [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html#Queries) for a full list of possible values.

Other args such as `:max_results` have also changed to 'max-results'. The links in to the api docs list all the possible args. Hope that helps.